# mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) vs $result->fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch, resultset

I wonder what's the difference between these two ways to extract data from a result, which one is the faster and more modern cause both of them work with mysqli.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: There is no practical difference. both will give you your row data in an associative array

Comment: you could look at the manual

Comment: non of them is modern, the difference is that first one is procedural style and the second is object oriented [read more...](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli has [two different APIs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) for access. One, is a purely functional interface, using `mysqli_*` functions, and is somewhat similar to the interface used by the older `mysql` extension. The other API is an OOP interface.

In practical effect, both interfaces accomplish exactly the same thing. Assuming `$db` is a `mysqli` object retrieved from either `mysqli_connect` or `new mysqli`, these two lines mean exactly the same thing:

```
 $db->query('query string');
 mysqli_query($db, 'query string');
```

and in fact, at an engine level, are basically aliases of each other. Neither one is going to be faster than the other.

You should use whichever one is most comfortable to you, though OOP style is generally more widespread, and both work equally well.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answers, i'm managing tables with more than 30k records and this information was very important to me.